# How to remove the empty row in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

[image]

I was wondering how to remove row 4 and 10. I have tried dropna and fillna but there was no change

```
df = pd.read_csv("reasoncode.csv",encoding='utf-8-sig')

df["config"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv("reasoncodes.csv", encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: first you should use `print()` to see what you have in these rows.

Comment: Share some csv data so that I can try as well. Check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
dfnew = df[df.config!= '']
```

Considering that `id` is the primary key here. This is basically filtering out those rows where the primary key is not there. This would remove those columns with that field as empty in the new dataframe.